# What's the best way to split admin-only functionality in the theme's functions.php file?

Tags: filters, actions

I am customising a Wordpress admin area and so far so good with a number of add_filter and add_action calls in my theme's functions.php file.

But I'm a bit worried because all this code will be executed on all pages, not just the admin area.

I therefore went ahead with the below approach:

```
if (is_admin())
    require_once('admin-functions.php');
```

It works but is this the cleanest way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you do it is fine.

Also have a look at how Tom McFarlins [WordPress Plugin Boilerplate](https://github.com/tommcfarlin/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate) does it:

```
if ( is_admin() && ( ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) || ! DOING_AJAX ) ) {    
     require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'admin/class-plugin-name-admin.php' );
     add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'Plugin_Name_Admin', 'get_instance' ) );    
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/tommcfarlin/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate/blob/547319a8b667925d498fd5c6e478670b5655127d/plugin-name/plugin-name.php#L70-L91)